# Why doesnt this piece of code work within button click for label to equal text

Tags: vb.net

Why does this piece of text in a button click not work? Label68 is a integer, so if it is less than 0 then I want the TextBox191 field to equal Team 2 (as they have won), if the label equals numbers from 1-1000 i want the winner to be team 1 shown in textbox191 and thhen if the label equals 0 i want the textbox to equal draw as the game will be a draw

```
Private Sub Button12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
        If Label68.Text = >0 Then
            TextBox191.Text = "Team 2!"
        ElseIf Label68.Text = 1 - 10000 Then
            TextBox191.Text = "Team 1!"
        ElseIf Label68.Text = 0 Then
            TextBox191.Text = "Draw!"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a riddle? I mean because of the meaningless control names andd the missing issue/error.

Comment: can you elaborate your problem?

Comment: my guess is that `ElseIf Label68.Text = 1 - 10000 ...` doesnt do what you think it does

Comment: can you tell which condition is not working?

Comment: So is 0 (zero) a win for "Team 2" or a "Draw"?...

Comment: My only suggestion: switch  `OPTION STRICT`to `on` immediately and use control names like `TxtTeam`. Otherwise, how do you know what `TextBox423` displays?

Comment: You should use a **variable** to track this value (score?) instead of storing/retrieving it in the Text() property of a GUI control.

Comment: To use a "range" syntax like "1 - 1000", if that is what that's supposed to be, take a look at a `Select Case` statement instead.

Comment: Label68 is a integer, so if it is less than 0 then I want the TextBox191 field to equal Team 2 (as they have won), if the label equals numbers from 1-1000 i want the winner to be team 1 shown in textbox191 and thhen if the label equals 0 i want the textbox to equal draw as the game will be a draw

Comment: how can you label68 is integer? it clearly seems to be textbox

Comment: Label68 is not an Integer, it's a Label.  The Text() property is not an Integer, it's a String.

Comment: @TimSchmelter am i wrong? actually i meant lable

Comment: putting **numerals** into a textbox or label does not make them a numeric type. the property you are using is `.Text` so the data is `string`.  it is like saying `if "cat" +1 > "dog" then..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few issues here.

First, `ElseIf Label68.Text = 1 - 10000 Then` doesn't do what you think it does.  What you are actually saying is `ElseIf Label68.Text = -99999 Then`, which is probably not what you are trying to do.

Second, as others have stated, you really should have `Option Strict On` and you really should be saving these values to properly-typed variables and performing comparisons on the variables.

This is a really simplistic example, but you are probably looking for something like this:

```
Private Sub Button12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click

        Dim points As Integer = 0
        If IsNumeric(Label68.Text) Then
            points = CInt(Label68.Text)
        End If

        If points = 0 Then
            TextBox191.Text = "Draw!"
        ElseIf points > 0 AndAlso points <= 10000 Then
            TextBox191.Text = "Team 1!"
        ElseIf points < 0 Then
            TextBox191.Text = "Team 2!"
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment on the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I must admit i made mistake in downvoting. I didnt intended to downvote it. Can you edit your answer and add just space or something then i can upvote it.

Comment: There you go. Sorry again

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    If Label68.Text < 0 Then
        TextBox191.Text = "Team 2!"
    ElseIf Label68.Text > 1  and Label68.Text < 10000 Then
        TextBox191.Text = "Team 1!"
    ElseIf Label68.Text = 0 Then
        TextBox191.Text = "Draw!"
    End If
End Sub
```